# Excel4Macro Show.ToolBar sets CutCopyMode to false

Tags: excel, vba

I hide most of the Excel GUI in a workbook I'm developing in the Workbook_Activate event as it's a dashboard and needs a lot of screen space. In the Workbook_Deactive event I enable the toolbars again so the user can work as normal in another workbook. This is done with the following line:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"",true)"
```

When switching to another workbook the copy buffer is lost. I stepped through to this line and found it's the culprit, Application.CutCopyMode is set to false when this line executes.

Is there any way to run the Show.ToolBar code and retain the copy buffer?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can retain it as such, but you could add some functionaly to save it while you fiddle with the toolbar. Example: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=66405

Comment: Thanks, I like their use of a DataObject, though it requires a reference - I wonder if it could be late bound? In any event I was hoping there might be a clean way without workarounds.